# Ionic3 :Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, ionic3

### Ts

```
this.myservice.online_service('online_service',data).subscribe(res=>{
        this.result = res;

        this.bus_data=this.result.searchResult;
    })
```

### Html

```
<ion-card  *ngFor= "let bus of bus_data ; let i = index" [attr.data-target]="'#viewseat' + i" (click)="get_seats(i)">
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col col-6 class="p0 bus_name">{{bus.operatorName}}</ion-col>
 </ion-row>
</ion-card-header>
 </ion-card>
```

### service.ts

```
online_service(url,data = null )
{

this.show_loader();
return this.http.post(this.webservice_url+ url,  JSON.stringify(data)).map(res=>res.json())
}
```

The code works well if server returns multiple data .But getting this error in case server return single data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank a lot for your answers. Appreciate your efforts. I forget to check array type of data that come from server.Now it works perfectly

Let me post the right answer

```
this.myservice.online_service('online_service',data).subscribe(res=>{
      this.result = res;

      this.bus_data=this.result;
 if (this.bus_data.code === '1') {
    if (this.bus_data.searchResult instanceof Array !== true) {
       this.bus_data.searchResult = new Array(this.bus_data.searchResult);
   }}
   console.log(this.bus_data);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Which means you need to always use array to bind with ngFor. you could create a local variable and declare it as an array and then push the result.

```
myResult : any = [];
```

and then,

```
this.myservice.online_service('online_service',data).subscribe(res=>{
        this.result = res;
        myResult.push(this.result.searchResult);
})
```

Comment: Also use myResult with ngFor

Answer (score 1):

You need to push them to the array as follows.

In your component.ts define the array like this.

```
bus_data: any[] = [];
```

Now, inside your data loading function,

```
this.myservice.online_service('online_service',data).subscribe(res=>{
   this.result = res;
   this.bus_data=[...this.result.searchResult];
})
```

Comment: Now it displays in case of single data , and shows empty in case of multiple data. `<ion-content class="background" *ngIf="bus_data" [ngClass]="lang=='ar' ? 'ar' : ''">
    <ion-card  *ngFor= "let bus of bus_data ; let i = index" [attr.data-target]="'#viewseat' + i" (click)="get_seats(i)">
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col col-6 class="p0 bus_name">{{bus.operatorName}}</ion-col>` . Same bus_data[] declared as array